# Facebook like button without stay connected button

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm making and tablet application to a store, and the application needs to have the facebook like button, to a client click in it, but the problem is that the device is public and I'm afraid to use the like button and some one click in the stay connected button and another one login in the another person account, how can I make a like button that the user logs in like the store and logout automatically?

The application can use the web SDK of facebook, it isn't necessary to use the android SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
// user is now logged out
});
```

Check out this site for more information:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/